# PHP: cannot set a cookie

Tags: php, html, cookies

I want to set a cookie but it wont work. Im pretty new in PHP but I searched on the internet how to set a cookie, but it doesn't work.

```
<div id="content">
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['search-item']) && !isset($_COOKIE["searchRequest"])) {
        setcookie("searchRequest", $_GET['search-item']);
        include 'search_engine.php';
    }
    else {
        $page = $_COOKIE['page'];
        if(isset($page)){
            require_once $page;
        }
        else {
            require_once 'startpage.php';
        }
    }

?>
</div>
```

I really dont know what Im doing wrong :( Can someone help me and explain why this wont work. Everything else works flawlessly

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? There's no use care for it to fail.

Comment: @Alex That's not needed for cookies

Comment: I checked the setted cookies on my browser

Comment: Do you want to get hacked? Because this is how you get hacked. Cookies are stored on the *user's computer* and they can modify them to whatever they want.

Comment: You also mispelled `COOKIE` on the `3`rd line.

Comment: ....ya kinda have to wonder why they came up with those in the first place.

Comment: @D4V1D thats not the point it happend by modify my question

Comment: Well, correct it if you want SO users to focus on your main problem. - Edit: ty

Comment: and the name of the file containing presented code has .php extension? If it is .html, it will not work.

Comment: of course it is .php i will notice it if isnt. The PHP code will output it in a text if .html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enable error reporting:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

then you should see following:

```
 PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

Because you cannot output anything before setcookie, and you do here:

```
<div id="content">
```

Manual says:

> Like other headers, cookies must be sent before any output from your
>   script (this is a protocol restriction). This requires that you place
>   calls to this function prior to any output, including  and
>    tags as well as any whitespace.

Just move it after you set a cookie:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['search-item']) && !isset($_COOKIE["searchRequest"])) {
        setcookie("searchRequest", $_GET['search-item']);
        echo '<div id="content">';
        include 'search_engine.php';
    }else{
        echo '<div id="content">';
        if(isset($_COOKIE['page'])){
            $page = $_COOKIE['page'];
            require_once $page;
        }else{
            require_once 'startpage.php';
        }
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

And beware : it is not safe to include file that comes from cookie, I hope you just experiment, and it is not a part of serious code.

Comment: if I use `ob_start();
// setcookie(...)
ob_end_flush();` it show the same warning message

Comment: ob_start before any output, at the top.

Comment: and still the same warning? or no warning but doesn't set a cookie?

Comment: same warning message as before

Comment: also change `isset($page)` to `isset($_COOKIE['page'])` like in my answer. Try echo those divsafter setcookie like in my edited version.

Comment: I do excactly the same you do but i got every time the same warning messages

Comment: it says that some output was sent - find it and eliminate - maybe your file is also included in another file that outputs html, or maybe '<?php' is not the first thing from top - not even one space is allowed